# Hide the small logo in the toast notification windows 8

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, toast

I'm using this code to show a toastnotifcation in my application:

```
var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02);
var image = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image")[0];
var title = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0];

var text = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[1];

image.Attributes[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/logovboardnotif.png"));

title.AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Board"));

text.AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));


var toastnotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

var toastnotification = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

toastnotifier.Show(toastnotification);
```

My problem is when the toast is shown, there's a small logo (azure color):
[image]

How can I hide this logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

According to [Programming Windows® 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript by Microsoft Press](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9780735672604/chapter-13-tiles-notifications-the-lock-screen-and-background-tasks/ch13lev1sec5_html) `There are no means to override this; the branding attribute in the XML is ignored for toasts.`

---

You have to set `branding` attributte to `none`, default is `logo`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230843.aspx) try the below given code.

```csharp
var xml = @"<toast>
                <visual>
                    <binding template=""ToastImageAndText02"" branding=""none"">
                        <image id=""1"" src=""{0}""/>
                        <text id=""1"">{1}</text>
                        <text id=""2"">{2}</text>
                    </binding>  
                </visual>
            </toast>";

xml = string.Format(xml, "ms-appx:///Assets/Images/logovboardnotif.png", "Board", message);
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
var toastnotification = new ToastNotification(xmlDoc);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastnotification);
```

Comment: Does that still work? i added the 'branding' attribute but the icon is still showing